# JPA/Hibernate exception handling

Tags: hibernate, exception, jpa

I'm using JPA/Hibernate (a newbie at them). When an exception occur (could be an unique constraint violation) I want to catch it and show some application meaning messages, instead of printing the stack trace.

Does Hibernate provide some tool to get info (maybe database independent) about exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HibernateException **encapsulates the actual root cause** than can provide you enough information for you to generate meaningful user-friendly messages. Read the [Exception Handling](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/transactions-demarcation-exceptions.html) section of their documentation.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like following. i did that. But offcourse you are using vendor specific code so if you go with a different JPS provider, you will have to change code at several  places. At the same time, sometimes its practical when you know you are not gonna change JPA provider easily and user friendly error message is more important

```
try{
...
}

catch( javax.persistence.PersistenceException  ex)

{

     if(ex.getCause() instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)

      {..........}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either catch the general `JDBCException`:

```
try {
    userDao.save(user); //might throw exception
} catch(JDBCException e) {
    //Error during hibernate query
}
```

or you can also catch one of the more specific subclasses of `JDBCException` such as `ConstraintViolationException` or `JDBCConnectionException`:

```
try {
    userDao.save(user); //might throw exception
} catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    //Email Address already exists
} catch(JDBCConnectionException e) {
    //Lost the connection
}
```

and with the `e.getCause()` method you can retrieve the underlying `SQLException` and analyse it further:

```
try {
    userDao.save(user); //might throw exception
} catch(JDBCException e) {
    SQLException cause = (SQLException) e.getCause();
    //evaluate cause and find out what was the problem
    System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
}
```

Which would print for example: `Duplicate entry 'UserTestUsername' for key 'username'`

Answer (score 1):

You can specifically catch org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException. That way you know you're catching only constraint issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch Hibernate Exceptions when you want to call `Flush()` on your Session  or `commit()` on your Transaction.

```
try {
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Hibernate Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
    
// or

try {
    session.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Hibernate Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All exceptions in Hibernate are derivatives of the Java's RuntimeException class. So if you catch a RuntimeException in your code , you can fetch the cause of the exception by calling the Exception class' getCause() or getMessage() methods

Comment: You should avoid catching such general exceptions as RuntimeException. Catched Exceptions should be as specific as it is possible.